# Como hacer un li

Tags: css

```css
/* General */
body{
  background-color: #000000;
}

/* ------- */

/* 1.0 - Menu de navegación */

#menu{
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#menu li{
  float: left;
}
#menu li:first-child > a{
  background-color:gray;
}
#menu li a{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
  display:block;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-decoration:none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
#menu li a:hover{
  background-color:gray;
}
/* ------------------------- */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Astro cosmos</title>
  <link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/7.0.0/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
<body>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="home.html">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="maths.html">Matemáticas</a></li>
    <li><a href="physics.html">Física</a></li>
    <li><a href="computacion.html">Computación</a></li>
    <li><a href="others.html">Otros</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

***Como podría hacer para que el tamaño horizontal del menú sea del tamaño del body, osea adaptable a cualquier ventana.
Solo con css***

Comment: ¿usas bootstrap o algun framework?, de esamanera es muy sencillo adaptar tu navbar menu al espacio completo de la pantalla, es mas puedes mantenerlo si haces un scroll.

Comment: Uso normalize css, pero no funciona

Comment: Intenté con 100% de width y 100vw de width, pero nada

Comment: Te recomiendo descargar Bootstrap que trae ya creado ciertos navbar menú y es muy complejo en cuanto a creación  de vistas: http://getbootstrap.com/ si lo descargas avísame por ayuda y te indico como dejarlo al 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/calc) para que te calcule la anchura del elemento `li` *on the fly*:

```
#menu li {
  float: left;  
  text-align: center;
  width: calc(100% / 5); /* Cantidad de elementos li */
}
```

```css
body{  
  background-color: #000000;
}

#menu li {
  float: left;  
  text-align: center;
  width: calc(100% / 5); /* Cantidad de elementos li */
}

#menu {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0; 
}

#menu li:first-child > a{
  background-color:gray;
}

#menu li a{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
  display:block;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-decoration:none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

#menu li a:hover{
  background-color:gray;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="home.html">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href="maths.html">Matemáticas</a></li>
  <li><a href="physics.html">Física</a></li>
  <li><a href="computacion.html">Computación</a></li>
  <li><a href="others.html">Otros</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
/* General */
body{
  background-color: #000000;
}

/* ------- */

/* 1.0 - Menu de navegación */

#menu{
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align: center;
}
#menu li{
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}
#menu li:first-child > a{
  background-color:gray;
}
#menu li a{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
  display:block;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-decoration:none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
#menu li a:hover{
  background-color:gray;
}
/* ------------------------- */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Astro cosmos</title>
  <link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/7.0.0/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
<body>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="home.html">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="maths.html">Matemáticas</a></li>
    <li><a href="physics.html">Física</a></li>
    <li><a href="computacion.html">Computación</a></li>
    <li><a href="others.html">Otros</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero que te sirva si es lo que buscas.

Comment: Dividiste solo el 100/5 cada li, no??

Comment: sii le puse un width de 20% a tus li, si vas agregar mas li, pues ya tienes que jugar con el porcentaje del ancho, cualquier duda me cuentas.

Comment: @EduardoSebastian si crees que mi respuesta fue suficiente puedes aceptarla?

Answer (score 1):

```
#menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%; // YOU NEED IT IN YOUR CODE
}
#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    text-align: center;  
    height: 100vh;
    width: 20%; // AND IT TOO :)
}
#menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    font-family: monospace;
    width:16vw;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/adivirgilio/5mzzayyq/4/